# Batch While loop

Tags: loops, batch-file, cmd, while-loop, goto

I am trying to create a While(server not reachable) loop. There is no `while` in batch files, but it can be done with `goto`.  So I have some code that is checking if a server is reachable, if not it will try again after 5 sec. If it is reachable it will restart the server.

Here is what I tried:

```
:loop
for /f "delims=" %a in ('curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://localhost:8080/project/html5/') do @set status=%a
if %status% == 404 (
    echo Server not reachable... trying again...
    timeout /T 5 /nobreak
    goto loop
) else (
    if %status% == 000 ( 
        echo Server offline... trying again...
        timeout /T 5 /nobreak
        goto loop
        echo GOTO NOT WORKING!
    ) else (
        echo Server reachable! SUCCESS!
    )
)
```

It always prints "GOTO NOT WORKING!" but how is this possible? I also tried "goto :loop", but its also not working...

After that I have tried a simple endless loop with:

```
:loop
echo TEST
GOTO loop
```

This is working... WHY?! Its the same without an If-expression...

Comment: There is a double percent missing in the parameter of your `for` command: `for /f "delims=" %%a in ( ... @set status=%%a`

Comment: Also change your `if %status% == 404` and `if %status% == 000` to `if "%status%"=="404"` and `if "%status%"=="000"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
:loop    
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
        curl -s -o nul -w "%%{http_code}"  http://localhost:8080/project/html5/
    ') do set "status=%%a"

    if "%status%"=="404" (
        echo Server not reachable... trying again...
    ) else if "%status%"=="000" (
        echo Server offline... trying again...
    ) else (
        echo Server reachable! SUCCESS!
        goto :continue
    )

    timeout /t 5 /nobreak
    goto :loop

:continue
```

Changes made:

- Inside batch files the `for` replaceable parameters need a double percent sign, `%a` is used for command line, `%%a` inside batch.
- In windows to write to a nul device `/dev/nul` is not used, just `nul`
- Inside batch files the percent signs not related to variables need to be escaped, doubling them. It has to be done for the `-w "%%{http_code}"
- Just in case the `status` is not defined, it is better to quote the values in the `if` conditions, or execute a previous check (`if not defined status ...`)

Comment: Thank you thats working! I tried to double the "%" at the "A"'s but forgot it at the HTTP_CODE... thanks!

Also its pretty nice to see what you changed and how you changed the code style itself

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try :

```
:loop
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://localhost:8080/project/html5/') do @set status=%%a
if not defined status echo Error, Check your Program && Pause>Nul
if %status% == 404 (
    echo Server not reachable... trying again...
    timeout /T 5 /nobreak
    goto loop
) else (
    if %status% == 000 ( 
        echo Server offline... trying again...
        timeout /T 5 /nobreak
        goto loop
        echo GOTO NOT WORKING!
    ) else (
        echo Server reachable! SUCCESS!
    )
)
```

I dont know if in your for loop is a problem, but without it and a blank variable it will work.